# Подсчитать повтор слова в строке

Tags: kotlin

Прошу Вас подсказать как можно реализовать подсчет слова в строке. Читал на множестве форумах о существовании и использовании методов split, groupingBy и тд. Но это не увенчалось успехом... прошу наставить на путь истинный.

Для примера можно использовать строку :KLPQYM BUG KHQR KLPQYM JVOJTD JVOJTD BUG BUG KHQR BUG KLPQYM JVOJTD KLPQYM JVOJTD QLSPA KHQR JVOJTD KLPQYM JVOJTD KLPQYM KLPQYM JVOJTD JVOJTD BUG KLPQYM KHQR JVOJTD KHQR KLPQYM KLPQYM JVOJTD KLPQYM BUG BUG BUG. Где требуется найти число повторений слова BUG(P.S: ответ 8. Просто, чтобы не тратили время на подсчет). Спасибо!

Comment: Разбей на слова по пробелу и цикл for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейший вариант:

```
val str = "KLPQYM BUG KHQR ..."
var count = 0
for (word in str.split(" ")) {
    if ("BUG" == word)
        count++
}
println(count)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо Вам за помощь. Но можете объяснить почему в коде фигурирует слово word. Я просто только вчера начал заниматься Kotlin и немного не понятно

Comment: Просто в Java все переменные должны быть инициализированными, а тут нет)

Comment: Я к сожалению не настолько хорошо знаю джаву/котлин чтобы объяснить почему word не надо инициализировать.

Comment: Ладно. Попробую сам разобраться. Спасибо!